# Python Tkinter - How to make a description pop up for a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I simply don't know where to start, so I don't have any code. Does anyone know a way to make a description pop up when you hover over a button, or any widget for that matter?

Comment: *"I simply don't know where to start"* - then you are not yet ready to ask a question here.

Answer (score 0):

```
def button_description(button, text, self):
    event = None
    self.del_search_description = lambda event=event: del_search_description(self)
    self.search_description = lambda event=event: search_description_delay(self, text, button)
    button.bind("<Enter>", self.search_description)
    button.bind("<Leave>", self.del_search_description)
def del_search_description(self, event=None):
    try:
        self.search_description_top.destroy()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return event
def search_description_delay(self, text, button, event=None):
    button.after(500 , search_description(self, text, button ,event))
def search_description(self, text, button, event=None):
    self.search_description_top = Toplevel()
    self.search_description_top.wm_overrideredirect(True)
    self.search_description_top_label = Label(self.search_description_top,
                                          text=text,
                                          justify=LEFT, background="gold",
                                          relief=SOLID, borderwidth=1, font='50')
    self.search_description_top_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    x = button.winfo_rootx() - int(len(
    self.search_description_top_label.cget("text")) * 3.5) + int(button.winfo_width()/2)
    y = button.winfo_rooty() + 25
    self.search_description_top.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))
    return event
```

Call the button_description function, and provide the button, or other widget, the text to put on the description, and the class where your tkinter code is running (pass the word self if you are within the class where your code is)